# How do I view the definition of a type using Visual Studio Code's plugin for Elm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm

How do I view the definition of a type using Visual Studio Code's plugin for Elm?

**Example:**

I want to view the union cases for the type *Http.Error*.

In Visual Studio 2017, I would place the cursor on the type name and hit "F12" or right-click and select "View Definition".

However, in Visual Studio Code, I do not see how to do this.

Any suggestions?

**Appendix:**

```
import Http exposing (..)

..

type Msg
    = MorePlease
    | NewGif (Result Http.Error String) // Http.Error is a Discriminated Union type. But how would I examine its union cases?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VS Code plugin that I've seen yet offers for elm the sort of introspection offered by, say, JS and TypeScript plugins. Such tooling will catch up, but isn't there yet.